# openmcu+gnugk+ekiga

Tags: video, video-conferencing, h.323

I've got openmcu server installed and wanna to use gnugk with it, but actually can't find any manuals of how can I configure it. Could you, please, point to any or tell how can gnugk can be configured-started-used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the manual for GnuGk on the [hompage](http://www.gnugk.org/gnugk-manual.html) and there is also an [example with OpenMCU](http://www.gnugk.org/phone-conferencing.html).

Comment: ow, thanks! I'll try it. and could you please tell, if you know, how ekiga can be used with openmcu call & video server